# Selenium Web Driver - How can I find elements with tag name and class name together

Tags: java, selenium, attributes

If I used the tagname it brings me too many elements, If I use the class name it also bring too many elements, How can I combine between this two ???
I am using selenium webdriver with java, in intelij
Thanks!

My code now:
List roomname = driver.findElements(By.className("HDroomSelection").className("HDfirstCol").className("HDroomInfo").tagName("h3"));

The response still give me some lines that doesn't related, a few h3 tags that doesn't have the other attributes :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: First of all, show the code you have so others can help you to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

By using css selector one can combine the criteria. If you want to find button say has below html

```
<button class="buttonclass" />
```

Then following code should select the button

```
private By button = By.cssSelector("button.buttonclass");
driver.findElement(button).
```

css selector above in general format is

```
tag.classname
```

Comment: Here are a couple CSS Selector references... https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors and https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors.